# Track Desktop Application Session

Tags: c#, wpf, wmi

I am developing a WPF appllication which has to track session of desktop applications.I have used `ManagementEventWatcher` it works as expected, but my WPF application needs to be run as administrator. The users of the application will not have admin rights so the users getting `Access is denied` exception.

Even while developing my application in Visual Studio, to query this ManagementEventWatcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_ProcessStopTrace") the Visual studio has to be run as administrator.

How to get the stopped event processes without admin right?Is there other way so that i can get the stopped processes?

Below is the code i have used:

```
processStopEvent = new ManagementEventWatcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_ProcessStopTrace");

processStopEvent.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(processStopEvent_EventArrived);
processStopEvent.Start();

void processStopEvent_EventArrived(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
{
   string processName = e.NewEvent.Properties["ProcessName"].Value.ToString();
   string processID = Convert.ToInt32(e.NewEvent.Properties["ProcessID"].Value).ToString();

    if (processName.ToUpper().Contains(processname.ToUpper().Replace(".EXE", "")))
    {
           //closed/disconnect desktop log
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your app starting the process itself?

Comment: We have automated auto login for some of the desktop application, that will run when user clicks connect button. So these desktop application runs from other process so wont get actual desktop process.

Comment: Ok. How does your code gets deployed on the user computer? e.g. do you install anything and can you install an NT Service and run that as localsystem?

Comment: This is a ClickOnce application. The users have access to install the application

Comment: Ok. What about this API? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z3w4xdc9(v=vs.110).aspx You might be able to get Process instance using the name and then subscribe to Exited event?